# Cannot connect to visible WiFi networks running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom

I can now turn on and off the WiFi Adapter from the desktop menu. When it's on I can see all the WiFi networks around me, however I cannot establish a connection.

Here is the most useful output I can get.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Network -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4464] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:07bf]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57766 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1686] (rev 01)
```

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on        

enxd6f46f983b7a  no wireless extensions
```

```
$ nmcli dev wifi
Cell 02 - Address: 2C:30:33:73:96:2E
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=63/70  Signal level=-47 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Telstra2D55"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 56ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000B54656C7374726132443535
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 0706415520010D24
                    IE: Unknown: 200100
                    IE: Unknown: 23021500
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

Can anyone spot anything? I see the network, I connect as usual, enter the password and after 10 seconds or so it just keeps asking me again for my password.
Edit:

```
sudo dmesg | grep brcm
```

[    6.862585] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    6.862614] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.969173] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac4364-pcie for chip BCM4364/3
[    7.589183] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[    7.589185] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[    7.590453] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac4364-pcie for chip BCM4364/3
[    7.740463] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4364/3 wl0: Oct 23 2019 08:32:36 version 9.137.11.0.32.6.36 FWID 01-671ec60c
[    7.780405] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
:)

Comment: You can connect for 10 seconds, or you cannot at all?
What do you see when you try connecting with a cable?

Comment: The output of `nmcli dev wifi` looks strange to me.
I see completely different info.

Comment: The lspci shows my BMC4364 card & the ncmli shows the actual modem that my card is detecting. I cannot connect at all but the timeout is approx' 10 seconds before it pops back up and asks for my password again.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep brcm`

Comment: @sancho-s-reinstatemonicacellio yes you are right my bad, that is the output of `sudo iwlist scan` not the nmcli but I cocked it up when editing out after moderators got to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran NetworkManager's GUI connection editor from the command line using

```
nm-connection-editor
```

System seems to accept entries when done in this gtk.
Working perfectly. Now I can put away the cable.
Edit: Still need to use modprobe to switch off/on each time I log in but that's on a different question.